# Causes of non possible `PyDict_DelItem`

Tags: python, c, api

I'm wondering what are the possible causes of -1 return value of the Python C-API function `PyDict_DelItem`.

I'm sure that the key and the values are present in the dictionary, but don't understand why sometimes I get -1 return value. I've found no documentation on the possible causes.

Comment: Seems that the object is not hashable, but and so not indexeable, but in fact when I remove that object from dictionary is correctly removed....

Answer (score 3):

From the [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/dictobject.c#l820):

- the first argument is not a dict (`PyDict_Check` test fails): raises `SystemError`.
- the key is not hashable: could raise `NotImplemented` or other exceptions, depends on the exact `__hash__` or `PyObject_Hash` hook implementation.
- the key was not found in the dict: raises `KeyError`.

You need to check for an [exception being set](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/exceptions.html#PyErr_Occurred) when -1 is returned by `PyDict_DelItem`, in any case.